# Random value while returning $_SERVER['HTTPS']

Tags: php, ssl, https, server, php-7

I've a strange comportement while i'm trying to detect if HTTPS is enabled or not:

```
$ssl=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http");
$expected=$ssl.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo $ssl.'<br/>';
echo $ssl.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'<br/>';
echo $ssl.'<br/>';
echo $ssl.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'<br/>';
```

The result:

```
http
https://<MYDOMAIN>/beta/test.php
http
http<MYDOMAIN>/beta/test.php
```

Why, on the second line, it says httpS but just before and after http ?

Running PHP: 7.4.20 (OPcache enabled)

Thank you

Comment: Can you remove all of the concatenation and just `echo $ssl;` twice? Does it still do it then?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the cache:

```php
opcache_reset(); // put this line before your code

// code...
```

Navigate to the file.
Then remove the line and try your test again.

Comment: No, not working already tried to invalidate this file and reset opcache, also restarted php (running php-fpm), always same comportement